# how to convert nested json payload into for Restassured POST call using Map?

Tags: rest-assured

```
{
   "@serviceName": "75MultipleService",
   "inputs": [
          {
            "@name": "inp1",
            "value": "8",
            "@type": "number"
          },
          {
           "@name": "inp2",
           "value": "8",
           "@type": "number"
     }
   ]
}
```

I am trying this but not understating how to pass input2

```
    Map <String, Object> map = new HashMap<> ();
    map.put("@serviceName", "75MultipleService");
    map.put("inputs", Arrays.asList(new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
        put("@name", "inp1");
        put("value", "8");
        put("@type", "number");
    }}));
```

How to pass nested json to post request?

Comment: What part of payload do you want to convert to a map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to pass input2

It's just another Map, you can do like this.

```java
Map<String, Object> input1 = Map.of("@name", "inp1", "value", "8", "@type", "number");
Map<String, Object> input2 = Map.of("@name", "inp2", "value", "8", "@type", "number");
Map<String, Object> payload = Map.of("@serviceName", "75MultipleService", "inputs", List.of(input1, input2));
```